# Get the current width of an UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell (subclass of `UITableViewCell`) and I have some `UITextField` in it whose relative position within the cell I want to choose.

So my code resembles that :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSInteger offset = 230;
        UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offset, 10, 95, 30)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:myTextField];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now my problem is that this works fine in portrait mode but in landscape mode I would like to adjust offset to simulate a right align of my textfield. Similarly, I would like to be able to adjust for an `iPad`.

How can I get the current width of my cell ?

I tried to use `self.contentView.frame.size.width` and `self.contentView.bounds.size.width` but both always return 320.

I know it sounds like a question that would have been asked thousand times but I haven't found anything...

NB : I am aware there will be issues to handle with reusing cells but I have not gotten to this point yet.

Comment: Why not use NSLayoutConstraints?

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr  Could you be more specific ?

Comment: inside subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: go with NSLayoutConstraints, its easy to set from IB Or in viewDidLayoutSubviews of custom cell,  set x as (self.contentView.frame.size.width - 95), and add mytextfield. autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr question is how to get width of cell when device orientation change ,dats why.

Comment: If I get you right, you're interested in keeping your text field on some predicted distance from right side of your cell. You can achieve this by applying NSLayoutConstraint for this. It is pretty easy to set up one from IB or from code. You'll need four of them - fixed distance from right side of text field to right side of cell, width or left side fixed, anchor for top and bottom sides of text field (or one of them and height)

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr That's right. Would you have a pointer towards a more detailed explanation or a simple sample code ?

Comment: @jpulikkottil  your solution works perfect but I can't understand why... Why is `self.contentView.frame.size.width` always 320 whenever I log it ? Is it because the actual width is determined after the cell is initialized ? Anyhow, I will accept your answer if you write it as such

Comment: I think its adjusting only after that delegate, we will get correct value from viewDidLayoutSubviews as suggested by @shesh nath

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default size of `UITableViewCell` depending on xib(storyboard) if it's initialized from xib or storyboard.

If your cell initialized from code like this:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath]
```

So your cell will be initialized first(the size always `(320.0, 44.0)` whether iphone or ipad), and then be resized.

So you have to adjust the `width` of the `myTextField` while the `Cell`'s size changed.

There are 3 solutions:

**Use AutoLayout**:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:myTextField];

        myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[textField(==30)]"
                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:@{@"textField" : myTextField}]];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[textField(==95)]-0-|"
                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:@{@"textField" : myTextField}]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

**Use autoresizingMask as @jpulikkottil said:**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSInteger offset = 230;
        UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offset, 10, 95, 30)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:myTextField];
        mytextfield.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Use layoutSubviews**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        self.myTextField = myTextField;
        [self.contentView addSubview:myTextField];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; 

    NSInteger offset = self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 95;
    self.myTextField.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 10, 95, 30);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer ! 2d solution works great. I tried also the first one but using autolayout gives me :  `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`, and the textfield is not displayed (for either the vertical or the horizontal constraint). Don't know what could be at fault here

Comment: Set the `myTextField`'s `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`

Answer (score 1):

An example with NSLayoutConstraint (recommanded)

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:myTextField];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[textField(==95)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"textField",textField}]];
        //Add vertical constraints then
    }
    return self;
}
```

This fixes the textField to the contentView's right, and set its width to 95.
You still have to add verticals constraints but its not the point here.

edit: fixed runtime error

Comment: This looks great but this gives me `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`, and the textfield is not displayed. I guess I am doing something wrong somewhere else but I have no clue where. I worked my way out with another method though.

Comment: (this can be fixed as explained in the comment to the accepted answer).

Comment: indeed I forgot it ;)

Answer (score 0):

check cell size inside mention method

```
    -(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews 
     {       
                 NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];

             UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
             NSLog(@"width=%f",cell.contentView.frame.size.width);
     }
```

write this function inside viewcontroller.

Comment: I don' understand your answer. Where should I put this ?

Comment: @vib, subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: but this never gets called

Comment: i have modified answer please try this